# Buffer issue with an OpenGL ES 3D view in a Cocos2D app

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, buffer

I'm trying to insert an OpenGL ES 3D view in a Cocos2D app on the IPad. I'm relatively new to these frameworks, so I basically added those lines in my CCLayer:

```
CGRect rScreen;
// some code to define the bounds and origin of my frame
EAGL3DView * view3d = [[EAGL3DView alloc] initWithFrame:rScreen] ;

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview: view3d];

[view3d startAnimation]
```

The code I'm using for the 3D part is based on a sample code from Apple Developer : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html
The only changes I made were to create my view programmatically (no xib file, initWithCoder -> initWithFrame...), and I also renamed the EAGLView class & files to EAGL3DView so as not to interfere with the EAGLView that comes along with Cocos2D.

Now onto my problem: when I run these, I get an "OpenGL error 0x0502 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers]", the 3D view being properly displayed but with a completely pink screen otherwise.

I went into the swapBuffers function in Cocos2d EAGLView, and it turns out the only block of code that is important is this one:

```
if(![context_ presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES])
    CCLOG(@"cocos2d: Failed to swap renderbuffer in %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
```

which btw does not enter the "if" condition (presentRenderbuffer does not return a null value, but is not correct though since the CHECK_GL_ERROR() afterwards gives an 0x0502 error).

So I understand that there is some kind of incorrect overriding of the OpenGL ES renderbuffer by my 3D view (since Cocos2d also uses OpenGL ES) causing the Cocos2D view not to work properly. This is what I got so far, and I can't figure out precisely what needs to be done in order to fix it. So what do you think?

Hoping this is only a newbie problem…

Pixelvore

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to setup two separate OpenGL views. I wouldn't recommend it, if it is at all possible on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach for what you are trying to do is:

1. create your own custom CCSprite/CCNode class;
2. put all the GL code that you are using from the Apple sample into that class (i.e., overriding the `draw` or `visit` method of the class).

If you want to try and make the two GL views work nicely together, you could try reading [this post](http://gamesfromwithin.com/using-multiple-opengl-views-and-uikit), which will explain how you associate different buffers to your views.

As to the first approach, have a look at this [post](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/12108)  and [this one](http://www.deluge.co/?q=cocos-2d-custom-filled-polygon).

To be true, the first approach might be more complex (depending on how the Apple sample is doing open gl), but will use less memory and will be more optimized that the second.

Comment: I think I want to keep the kind of structure I showed (creating a subview in the CCDirector), because I did the same to insert a PDF reader and a movie player in the app and it worked just fine. In my mind CCSprites are just stickers with an image that you can blit on your screen (the SDL way), but maybe I'm wrong?

[edit] Thanks A LOT for your link though, it seems like exactly what I need. I'll look into it!

Comment: The fact is that the OpenGL pipeline is lot more "delicate" than other views that are already designed for insertion into other views. That is the reason why the link I gave resorts to handling a different buffer for each OpenGL view. This will have its cost in terms of memory, of course. On the other hand, a CCNode is the place where you can override the open GL drawing done by cocos2d. I will add a few links to my answer. In any case, I hope it helps.

Comment: I've looked into the multiple buffers solution and I still need to figure out how to make it work: I do have 2 different buffers, but the problem is that I have to bind them "at the same place" using glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, ...), and I think this is what causes the problem to occur. Seems like there's something I misunderstood in the way you attach your buffers after creating them.

I'll look into the CCNode solution, which indeed seems a bit complicated but looks like it can work in any case.

Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Comment: the second parameter to `glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, ...)` is a "name" for your buffer, so you should be able to keep the two of them separate. you could show your code... Also, check this link: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1932

Comment: Indeed it should. But the fact is it doesn't :D

I think I'm gonna head into the CCNode direction anyway. Should be fine.

Cheers!